# How to send a string in a socket?

Tags: c, json, string, sockets

I've a problem. I've to send a string to a server. If I send a constant string, escaping the double quotes, send is ok.

But, if I retrieve this string from json, server doesn't receive data correctly.

Constant string:

```
char string[] = " { \"param\": { \"status\": 0, \"tempID\": 1210254506, \"firmware\": \"alfa\" } } ";
```

String retrieved from json is the same, in fact, if I print it:

```
{ "param": { "status": 0, "tempID": 1210254506, "firmware": "alfa" } }
```

I think that the problem is the double quote escaping, that doesn't happen (in my opinion) retrivieng the string from a json object. Here is my code:

```
int fd;
if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    print_time();
    perror("Socket failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
//memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(9900);
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.96");
char string[] = " { \"param\": { \"status\": 0, \"tempID\": 1210254506, \"firmware\": \"alfa\" } } ";
const char * buf_cst =json_object_to_json_string(hb);

if (sendto(fd, string, sizeof(string), 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
{
    perror("Error");
}

close(fd);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you send your generated string? For the string literal you are using `sizeof string` which includes the terminating 0 byte that you probably do not want to send. How do you get length of your generated string?

Comment: i do strlen(buff), where buff is: strcpy(buff, json_object_to_json_string(json_obj)), but it is 0 or 1

Comment: Please show that code in your question. It is not helpful to show the version that works but not show the version you have a problem with. Also show what `buff` is.

Comment: You  mentioned the generated string is as expected. How can you get `strlen` being `0` or `1` then?

Comment: Please show the exact buffer that you send. I don't believe the problem has anything to do with the sending itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: there is a problem in ur string contatnt declaration, change it to - `char string[] =
        " { \"param\": { \"status\": 0, \"tempID\": 1210254506, \"firmware\": \"alfa\" }} ";`

Comment: @ReportFeedback You do not need to escape quotes in runtime-created string data. Note that as Gerhardh mentioned, `sizeof(string)` on a string literal will include the null-terminator in the length. But `strlen()` will not. Are you accounting for that difference when sending the generated string? Does the receiver expect to receive a null terminator to begin with? Since you are using UDP, null-terminating a string inside a datagram is not necessary, unless you need to separate it from other data in the same datagram (which you are not doing).

Comment: @ReportFeedback How exactly is the "server not receiving data correctly"? Are you getting a socket error? Garbage data? Please be more specific.

Comment: Start with printing the string you are sending on the client side. Does the server receive the same string you print? If yes, the server and client and socket communication are all irrelevant because they obviously work.